# N8000 File System: App

Tags: android, filesystems, apk

I need to have a look at the folder structure created by my Android application I deployed to an N8000 device.

I'm very new to Android developer and there seems to be no easy way to access the file system? I downloaded File Explorer on my device, but under Android/data/ I don't see my application, but it's definitely there if I open up the applications grid on the device.

Where or how would I find my application on the device without rooting it?

Comment: What do you need this for? Eclipse SDK has a file explorer which should be good enough for many things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this over USB using ADB. There are lots of explorer tools and command line options on how to do this. I prefer this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/files/ but there are lots of others if that one doesn't work for your needs. Just google ADB File Explorer.

Here's a command line as well for you: `adb shell ls -R /`

Comment: thank you. but this does not bring back the application i'm looking for either. it shows everything exception MY app. it's a phonegap application compiled to an apk and the deployed to device. might this be a reason?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, unless you're installing to someplace odd.. Is this an apk you can post? I can give it a try if it's not something proprietary..